# How to make Cocoapods to generate a bundle file

Tags: ios, cocoapods, resourcebundle, nsbundle

So I am creating an iOS static library project that will also support Cocoapods.

This library project will contain `js` files which you need to ship in a bundle (It won't compile into `.a` file). In the code, the way I reference these `js` files are, finding the bundle file first, then get the file from bundle. This works.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[
[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"resource" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
NSString* html = [bundle pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"js"];
```

However, in Cocoapods distrubtion, these resource files are configured using

```
s.ios.resource_bundle = { 
    'resources' => ['foo.js']
  }
```

And in code, you need to reference it by

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:...
```

There will be no custom bundle(`resource.bundle`) file anymore, all will be merged in `mainBundle`

Is there an universal way to references these js files? Thanks!